# System.IO.FileNotFoundException in delayed function

Tags: c#, exception, timer, timeout, windows-phone-8

In my winphone app I have a strange situation where I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` in code that does nothing related to files.

I have a class that manages delayed function calls:

```
// Delayed function manager
namespace Test
{
    public static class At
    {
        private readonly static TimerCallback timer = 
            new TimerCallback(At.ExecuteDelayedAction);

        public static void Do(Action action, TimeSpan delay,
            int interval = Timeout.Infinite)
        {
            var secs = Convert.ToInt32(delay.TotalMilliseconds);
            new Timer(timer, action, secs, interval);
        }

        public static void Do(Action action, int delay, 
            int interval = Timeout.Infinite)
        {
            Do(action, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delay), interval);
        }

        public static void Do(Action action, DateTime dueTime, 
            int interval = Timeout.Infinite)
        {
            if (dueTime < DateTime.Now) return;
            else Do(action, dueTime - DateTime.Now, interval);
        }

        private static void ExecuteDelayedAction(object o)
        {
            (o as Action).Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

And a class that manages ProgressIndicator state:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Indicator
    {
        public DependencyObject ThePage;
        public ProgressIndicator Progressor;
        public Indicator(DependencyObject page)
        {
            ThePage = page;
            Progressor = new ProgressIndicator();
            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(ThePage, Progressor);
        }

        // If set(true) then set(false) in one second to remove ProgressIndicator
        public void set(bool isOn)
        {
            Progressor.IsIndeterminate = Progressor.IsVisible = isOn; // Exception happens on this line
            if (isOn) At.Do(delegate { this.set(false); }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run `set(true)` method in code I get the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
```

Why is this happening and how can this be fixed?

Comment: If you just see the exception in the debugger (but it won't break execution) then don't worry, it's just Framework's way to resolve assemblies.

Comment: A stack trace is always useful when solving problems like this.

Comment: @Adriano, it's not just in debugger, ProgressIndicator does not actually disapper so the program does not function right.

Comment: @Martin Liversage do you mean a text displayed in "Call Stack" panel or something else?

Comment: @Anton: A .NET exception object contains a stack trace the describes the series of calls that led to the exception being thrown. If the exception is unhandled by your application you can run in the debugger which will break when the exception is thrown. You can then inside the debugger inspect the exception details including the stack trace. If instead you have a handler for the exception (a `catch`) you should log or display the exception (`ToString()`). This will include the stack trace.

Comment: @Martin Liversage, thanks, I've tried try-catch approach and it displayed `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access`. I still don't know what to do with that though. Can you please advice if I should edit this question and provide all the new info or delete it and post a new one?

Comment: Are you setting IsVisible to false from another thread (in the At.Do callback)? BeginInvoke it with the dispatcher! (I'm surprised you get a FileNotFoundException first...anyway...)

Comment: @Adriano I'm sorry I'm new to all of this. Do you mean I need to use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` in `ExecuteDelayedAction` method? `BeginInvoke` requires Async Callback as parameter and I have no idea what to put there. Can you please elaborate on all this stuff?

Comment: I **suppose** your At.Do method will invoke its parameter in another thread (or you're invoking set(true) from another thread). I suggest to put this check **inside the set() method** (so it'll be safe **wherever you'll call it**). Take a look at MSDN for an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your actual problem is permissions, the `FileNotFound` exception is probably happening as a result of not being able to read the file location directory.

I don't have any experience with Windows Phone development, however, I assume wherever `System.Windows.ni.dll` is resided requires higher permissions than what you are running your app under.

**Update**

Based on your call stack error message - "*Invalid cross-thread access*", the problem is your attempting to access/update a GUI component from another thread which isn't the UI thread. Try changing your code to:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
{ 
    Progressor.IsIndeterminate = Progressor.IsVisible = isOn;
    if (isOn) 
        At.Do(delegate { this.set(false); }, 1000);
}

});
```

Comment: OK, then how can these permissions problems be resolved and why do they happen?

Comment: "*how can these permissions problems be resolved*" - try giving whichever account you are running the app under read permissions to whichever directory `System.Windows.ni.dll` is in.

Comment: It did the trick, thanks. Perhaps you can recommend some literature on this topic because frankly I have no idea why this piece of code works and how I should resolve similar situations.

Comment: Well this problem isn't particular to windows phone, it's a general threading issue. In a nut shell, UI components tend to have thread affinity which, in simple terms, means they can only be accessed from the same thread on which they were created (the UI thread). So when you attempt to access it via a different thread (e.g. `TimerCallback`) it throws an exception. So how to resolve it in similar situtations is simply make sure when you access a GUI component it's running on the same thread it was created on - which `Dispatcher` does in your case.

Comment: @Anton So what permission you suppose to add? MY problem is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248301/system-io-filenotfoundexception-when-refereing-to-xaml-textbox-text-in-event-met