# How to use an existing sqlite database on windows phone 8 with cordova

Tags: c#, sqlite, cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-3

I'm building an hybrid app with cordova 3.0. I use a plugin to store my data in a sqlite database. On android and ios I have some scripts, which copy the database to the apps "documents" folder, where I can read/write to that pre filled database. Now I want to archive the same on windows phone 8.

I found a tutorial on:
http://wp.qmatteoq.com/import-an-already-existing-sqlite-database-in-a-windows-8-application/

But it's not cordova related.

This is what my code looks like:

```
namespace com.example.hello
{
   public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
   {
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.CordovaView.Loaded += CordovaView_Loaded;
    }

    private async void CordovaView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await CopyDatabase();
        this.CordovaView.Loaded -= CordovaView_Loaded;
    }

    private async Task CopyDatabase()
    {
        bool isDatabaseExisting = false;

        try
        {
            StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("my.db");
            isDatabaseExisting = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            isDatabaseExisting = false;
        }

        if (!isDatabaseExisting)
        {
            StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("my.db");
            await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
        }
    }
}
}
```

But I always get an exception "System.IO.FileNotFoundException". But the .db file is still at the right place. If I use a snippet to display all files in "ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder", my sqlite fill is still there.

I also have a gist with an screenshot https://gist.github.com/pille72/9615840

Comment: Could this possibly be related to file permissions? Check out [System.Io.FileNotFound Win7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972669/system-io-filenotfoundexception-in-delayed-function)

Comment: Did u find the solution ? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the build action from `Resource` to `Content`.